# Draggtable - dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use `jquery dragtable` http://plugins.jquery.com/dragtable/
My table is generated dynamically from json. Data in this table, is refreshing many times in the same view, but dragtable script **works only first time**. This is my code generating table header:

```
this.setHeader = function() {
    var table = "<thead><tr><th><div class=\"draggable-handler\"><h4>L.P.</h4></div></th>";

    for (var attr in AttrMap.map) {
        if ($("#" + attr + "-checkbox").prop('checked')) {

            table += "<th><div class=\"draggable-handler\"><h4>" + AttrMap.getNameByAttrName(attr) + 
                     "</h4></div><img class=\"" + ARROW_DOWN_CLASS + "\" src=\"" + ARROW_DOWN_SRC + "\"/></th>";

        }
    }
    table += "</tr></thead>";
    $("#table-id").append(table);
    $("#table-id").dragtable({dragHandle:'.draggable-handler'});
    $("img.sort-icon,img."+ ARROW_DOWN_CLASS + ",img." + ARROW_UP_CLASS).click(function(event) {
        onSortClick(event);
    });
};
```

Click event is registered correctly, function is invoked always, even after refresh data.

```
$("img.sort-icon,img."+ ARROW_DOWN_CLASS + ",img." + ARROW_UP_CLASS).click(function(event) {
        onSortClick(event);
    });
```

Why dragtable script works only first time?

http://jsfiddle.net/b35ohh3r/1/

Comment: Could you share your script in a jsfiddle perhaps? I have a feeling that .draggable-handler is getting replaced by something else in your script once it's moved.

Comment: that would be hard, because script it's really extensive, but i'm sure that it's only one handler for .draggable-handler

Comment: You should provide some simple jsfiddle that reproduces your issue, because even if someone will try to make the simple jsfiddle for you, likely he won't be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b35ohh3r/1/